# Generic DataAccess Layer in C# 3.5

Tags: generics, data-access-layer

What are the best practices to creating a Generic DataAccess Layer in C# 3.5. Dose LINQ to  SQL have any support for Other DataSources like MySQL , Oracle etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL is SQL Server only, and is likely to remain that way. If you want support for other databases then use [LINQ To Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386992.aspx). You can read a comparison between [LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities here](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/adoef_vs_linqsql.htm).

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75959/how-to-implement-database-independence-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you may want to investigate NHibernate. The learning curve is a bit steep, but there are many web resources to help you along the way.

It has native support for Sql Server, MySql, Oracle, Postgres, Sqlite, DB2 and others.

Comment: What would be my decision point for using NHIbernate instead on LTS?.